# How to design each mapper to handle each line of a SequenceFile?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sequencefile

I have a SequenceFile which is generated from previous MapReduce job. This SequenceFile has N lines, each line is a pair *key* and *value*, both are Text objects.

```
line1: key1 \t value1

line2: key2 \t value2

line3: key3 \t value3

...

lineN: keyN \t valueN
```

I use this SequenceFile as input of new MapReduce job. In this new MapReduce job, I want each mapper to handle several lines, eg 2 lines, of this SequenceFile, eg.

```
line1, line2 goes to mapper1

line3, line4 goes to mapper2

.....

line(N-1), lineN goes to mapperN
```

I could not use *NLineInputFormat* because it is used only for Text file. So, I used *SequenceFileInputFormat* and let Hadoop split the data into 40Mb each (my blocksize=40M).  Even each split is equal in size, there are mappers which receive much more data (i.e., lines) than others. Eg., 5 lines go to mapper1 while just 1 line goes to mapper2. Thus, the mapper2 finishes very fast while mapper1 takes so long time, and many times it fails due to Java heap size overflow.

[image]

I tried the following but none of them worked:

- Change blocksize:
- Increase number of mappers: The problem is still the same. Many mappers finish very fast because there is no input line, while there are several mappers take almost input, which never finish.
- Convert my SequenceFile to Text file, then use *NLineInputFormat*: I got Java heap size overflow because of the Text file takes too much RAM. That is why I want to use SequenceFile because it supports compression.

My question is:

**How to make each mapper get similar(or equivalent) number of input lines of a SequenceFile?**

Comment: You cannot control lines going to mappers unless each line is exactly the size of the HDFS block size. How much RAM do you have, and what YARN settings are you giving per container?

Comment: I have 5-node cluster, each of them has 8Gb RAM. Each node I gave 6.4Gb for container. I think I can not increase more.

Comment: Do you really only want one possible mapreduce attempt per node?

Comment: I have tried with lower Yarn settings such as 3GB, 4GB but Java heap size overflow occurred. So I increased up to 6.4Gb.

Comment: Can you help me to explain that  even the input of each mapper is 40MB, but why  there still be mappers which get no input line? I have changed to different blocksize (30MB, 50MB, 80MB,128MB...) such mappers still existed.

Comment: Did you re-upload the files after changing the block size? The initial blocks don't change after you edit the configs. Personally, I don't know how changing that value affects mappers since I've always left the default

Comment: Sure, I reloaded the file. I changed blocksize with the hope that input smaller block to a mapper --> the mapper has to process less --> Java heap size overflow will not occur. But I was wrong. For some reason, much data still go into a certain mapper while the other mappers get no data. Thus, java heap size overflow still occurred.

Comment: You cannot control how many lines goes to specific mapper, but you can control what data goes to which reducer. You can change your mapper to simply pass the data. Then create your custom partitioner, that will split the data evenly to the reducers. Then do the logic that requires lot of RAM in reducer.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you Luk.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control how many lines goes to specific mapper, but you can control what data goes to which reducer. You can change your mapper to simply pass the data. Then create your custom partitioner, that will split the data evenly to the reducers. Then do the logic that requires a lot of RAM in reducer.